# the name "###" doesn't exist in current context

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, namespaces

I have 2 files. In the first one, I declare a static class with a method.
When it comes to call it in the second file, I got an error stating that the name of the class does not exist in the current context. I think I have issues with namespaces which I don't really get very well.

File 1 : App_Code/SessionAccess.cs

```
namespace edpermdb.App_Code
{
   public static class SessionAccess
   {
      public static DataTable GetSessions()
      {...}
```

File 2: /default.aspx.cs

```
  namespace edpermdb
  {
     public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          liste.DataSource = SessionAccess.GetSessions();
          //on relie la liste à la source de données
          liste.DataBind();
```

SessionAccess in the default page is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Change the namespace in which you put `SessionAccess` to the same namespace as the `_default` class:

```
namespace edpermdb
{
   public static class SessionAccess
   {
      public static DataTable GetSessions()
      {...}
```

If that's not possible, add a `using edpermdb.App_Code` at the top of the second file.

Comment: I changed so that I can use the same namespace. But I still got the error. And when I go to the class explorer. I have the same name "edpermdb" for the 2 namespaces but with different files in it. the first one contains only the default.aspx.cs et in the second one, the rest of the files.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your class in the namespace `edpermdb.App_Code` and you are trying to use it in a different namespace. Specify `using edpermdb.App_Code;` before usage, or right click on the class name and select `Resolve` from the context menu.

```
using edpermdb.App_Code; //here
namespace edpermdb
  {
     public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          liste.DataSource = SessionAccess.GetSessions();
          //on relie la liste à la source de données
          liste.DataBind();
```

Comment: I tried to put that line, but the App_code doesn't exist in the namespace. that what it says.

Comment: @djasy3, Try commenting out the lines in page_load events, compile your web application and they uncomment those lines, see if the error goes away.

Comment: I did it, but when I uncomment, the error is still there.
I don't understand why, when I goes to the class explorer, it gives me 2 same namespaces but with different files in it.